# Alignment of text in unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Output must be like the below given image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdrox.jpg)

But the output for my code is like the below given image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIgIO.png)

My code:

```
<span>
<b>cannot contain</b>
<li>The "@" or "<" symbols </li>
<li> your SkyMiles number, email or username</li>
<li> More than 3 special characters </li>
</span>
```

Except span tag changes can be made on any tag even new tags can be added below span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ul` instead of `span` and keep the `b` tag out of `ul`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 4px 4px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<b>MUST BE</b>
<ul>
  <li>Between 8 and 20 characters</li>
  <li>At least 1 number</li>
  <li>At least 1 uppercase letter</li>
  <li>At least 1 lowercase letter</li>
</ul>
<br />
<b>CANNOT CONTAIN</b>
<ul>
  <li>The "@" or "
    < " symbols</li>
      <li>your SkyMiles number, email or username</li>
      <li>More than 3 special characters</li>
    </ul>
```